# MacTeX won't compile

Tags: installing, mac

Just installed MacTeX. Attempted to type set a file. Got this error:

> `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex` does not exist. TeXShop is a front end for TeX, but you also need a TeX distribution. Perhaps such a distribution was not installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to `http://tug.org/mactex` and follow the instructions to install MacTeX or BasicTeX.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Did you install TeXShop or MacTeX?

Comment: looks like you installed a editor but no LaTeX compiler.

Comment: I installed MacTex form tug.org. The full version, not the basic one.

Comment: Open a terminal and enter `which pdflatex`. What is the result?

Comment: This can't be answered without further input from the OP, so I'm voting to close.